# Android Instant App APKs

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Whenever I use command line to produce feature APKs, it produces 2 APK. My feature apk and base apk. However, I don't upload them to Play Store. It says : Sorry we could not save your changes" Whenever I use **Android Studio -> Build -> Generate Signed APK** it only produces my base feature apk and when I try to upload the zip folder to Play Store, it says "Your Feature APKs contains "productdetail" apk either does not exist or was not included". Any idea why can it happen? Or any help how to produce **v1+v2 signed** APKs to upload them to Play Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, there are some bugs building your Instant App via the Studio menus (Build -> Generate Signed APK). You should run gradle directly, either by using the far right gradle panel in Studio and executing the top level `assembleRelease` task or via command line (`./gradlew assembleRelease`).

If you haven't already, to setup gradle to sign your APKs (v1+v2) use `signingConfigs` as per [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-shared-keystore).

Each of your feature modules (including base) will need to have `signingConfigs` setup in their `build.gradle` file to ensure each feature APK is signed correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much! this is what I need!